# flink SQL 1.13.0&1.13.1 elasticsearch sink failed

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

```
Flink SQL> INSERT INTO es_sink SELECT 'hello';
[INFO] Submitting SQL update statement to the cluster...

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.table.client.SqlClientException: Unexpected exception. This is a bug. Please consider filing an issue.
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.SqlClient.startClient(SqlClient.java:201)
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.SqlClient.main(SqlClient.java:161)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.elasticsearch.table.RowElasticsearchSinkFunction.<init>(Lorg/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/elasticsearch/table/IndexGenerator;Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/flink/api/common/serialization/SerializationSchema;Lorg/apache/flink/elasticsearch7/shaded/org/elasticsearch/common/xcontent/XContentType;Lorg/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/elasticsearch/table/RequestFactory;Ljava/util/function/Function;)V
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.elasticsearch.table.Elasticsearch7DynamicSink.lambda$getSinkRuntimeProvider$0(Elasticsearch7DynamicSink.java:129)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.exec.common.CommonExecSink.createSinkTransformation(CommonExecSink.java:161)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.exec.stream.StreamExecSink.translateToPlanInternal(StreamExecSink.java:130)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.exec.ExecNodeBase.translateToPlan(ExecNodeBase.java:134)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.StreamPlanner$$anonfun$translateToPlan$1.apply(StreamPlanner.scala:70)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.StreamPlanner$$anonfun$translateToPlan$1.apply(StreamPlanner.scala:69)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.StreamPlanner.translateToPlan(StreamPlanner.scala:69)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.PlannerBase.translate(PlannerBase.scala:165)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.translate(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:1518)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeInternal(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:740)
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.local.LocalExecutor.lambda$executeModifyOperations$4(LocalExecutor.java:226)
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.context.ExecutionContext.wrapClassLoader(ExecutionContext.java:90)
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.local.LocalExecutor.executeModifyOperations(LocalExecutor.java:226)
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.cli.CliClient.callInserts(CliClient.java:518)
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.cli.CliClient.callInsert(CliClient.java:507)
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.cli.CliClient.callOperation(CliClient.java:409)
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.cli.CliClient.lambda$executeStatement$0(CliClient.java:327)
    at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:159)
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.cli.CliClient.executeStatement(CliClient.java:327)
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.cli.CliClient.executeInteractive(CliClient.java:297)
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.cli.CliClient.executeInInteractiveMode(CliClient.java:221)
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.SqlClient.openCli(SqlClient.java:151)
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.SqlClient.start(SqlClient.java:95)
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.SqlClient.startClient(SqlClient.java:187)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: Could you please check if the connector jar matches the Flink version?

Comment: ```root@8fcd04ab3185:/opt/flink/lib# flink -v
Version: 1.13.1, Commit ID: a7f3192
root@8fcd04ab3185:/opt/flink/lib# ls |grep elastic
flink-sql-connector-elasticsearch6_2.11-1.13.1.jar
flink-sql-connector-elasticsearch7_2.11-1.13.1.jar
root@8fcd04ab3185:/opt/flink/lib#```

Comment: In general, you shouldn't put connectors into lib but rather bundle them in your user code. For SQL, it may be a bit different. How do you execute your query?

Comment: SQL ：INSERT INTO es_sink SELECT 'hello';

SQL execution is normal in Flink 1.12.4

Answer (score 0):

With your comment it looks like you have to conflicting ES versions in your classpath.

Instead of putting the jars into `lib`, it would be best to [execute the `sqlClient` with the `-l` option](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/dev/table/sqlclient/).

Comment: root@1475b3cda2fc:/opt/flink/sql/hids_project# ls userlib/
flink-sql-connector-elasticsearch7_2.11-1.13.1.jar
root@1475b3cda2fc:/opt/flink/sql/hids_project#

Comment: sql-client.sh -i tables/tmp_es.sql -l userlib/

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.elasticsearch.table.RowElasticsearchSinkFunction